# InputMismatchException when trying to read an int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearch 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <Integer> a = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
        System.out.println("Enter elements of your array, input an alphabet in order to exit");
        while(input.hasNextInt()) //takes input from the user until data type becomes something other than int
        {
            int i = input.nextInt();
            a.add(i);
        }
        Collections.sort(a); //Sorts the arrayList
        System.out.print("Enter a value which you wish to search in the array- ");
        int value = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(contains(a,value));
    }




    public static String contains(ArrayList<Integer> a, int value) //Uses the binary search algorithm to search for an element in the arrayList
    {
        int low=0;
        int high=a.size()-1;
        while (low<=high)
        {
            int mid = (high + low)/2;
            if (value==a.get(mid))
            return value+" is present in the given array at   position "+(mid+1);
            else if(value<a.get(mid))
            high=mid-1;
            else
            low=mid+1;
        }
        return value+"is not present in the given array";
    }



}
```

This code is giving me an unusual error after I input all elements of the arrayList..
The error was:- 
Enter a value which you wish to search in the arrayException in   thread "main"

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:19)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program tell us :

> Enter elements of your array, input an alphabet in order to exit

then you loop as long as `int` are entered, and stop but the alphabet character is never read.

Then your program tell us

> Enter a value which you wish to search in the array

and directly try to read an `int` from the scanner

```
int value = input.nextInt();
```

but the input's next is still the alphabet character as you never read it hence the `InputMismatchException`.

The documentation on the exception is quite clear of it cause :

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

---

Now how to fix this ?

You could simply add a call to `input.next` when you exit the first reading loop in order to skip the alphabet character :

```
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    int i = input.nextInt();
    a.add(i);
}
input.next();
Collections.sort(a);
System.out.print("Enter a value which you wish to search in the array");
int value = input.nextInt();
```